# Launchctl starting Virtual Machine before USB is intitiated

Tags: usb, launchd, virtualization

I have a plist file located in /Library/LaunchDaemons that starts a Virtual Machine headless with Ubuntu on it.

The problem is however that USB probably isn't initiated before the VM is started, and hence an USB stick located in COM port /dev/ttyACM0 (on VM) isn't available.

Output from "VBoxManage showvminfo userver" when running an normal start:

```
Currently Attached USB Devices:
UUID:                        73eb5973-ce2a-4410-8820-4ec7376e3f1d
VendorId:                    0x0658 (0658)
ProductId:                   0x0200 (0200)
Revision:                    0.0 (0000)

Address:                     p=0x0200;v=0x0658;s=0x0000000c8eba2f72;l=0x14200000
```

And with an autostart:

```
Currently Attached USB Devices:    
<none>
```

Is there a way to delay startup of the script?

Comment: There probably is; however, you've provided no information in that area within the contents of your post and therefore a definitive answer cannot be provided. What language is the script written in and what is its content? If `bash` there is the `sleep` command. You could also incorporate a _loop_ checking for the existence of the necessary _process_ and then break out of the _loop_ to then load the VM.

Comment: The script is a #!/bin/sh script. I thought that during start-up the scripts are run sequentially, hence there is no points in adding a sleep command? Or to check the existence of a process?

Comment: Well, it was fixed by adding "sleep 5" to the startup script